# kinectのfacetrackを使って瞬きを検出したいのですが

Tags: c#, kinect

kinectのfacetrackを使ってまばたきを検出したいのですが、前処理として画像のトリミング(目の周辺部分)を行わなければならないと思うのですが、トリミング処理がうまく行きませんがうまくいきません。良い方法はありますでしょうか？使っている言語はC#です。どうかよろしくお願いします。

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


using Microsoft.Kinect;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.FaceTracking;

namespace FaceTrackingCamera
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml の相互作用ロジック
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // 解像度・フレームレート
        private ColorImageFormat rgbFormat = ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30;
        private const DepthImageFormat depthFormat = DepthImageFormat.Resolution320x240Fps30;

        // KinectSensorChooser
        private KinectSensorChooser kinectChooser = new KinectSensorChooser();

        // FaceTrackerオブジェクト
        FaceTracker faceTracker = null;

        // Kinectセンサーからの画像情報を受け取るバッファ
        private byte[] pixelBuffer = null;

        // Kinectセンサーからの深度情報を受け取るバッファ
        private short[] depthBuffer = null;

        // Kinectセンサーからの骨格情報を受け取るバッファ
        private Skeleton[] skeletonBuffer = null;

        // 画面に表示するビットマップ
        private RenderTargetBitmap bmpBuffer = null;

        // ビットマップへの描画用DrawingVisual
        private DrawingVisual drawVisual = new DrawingVisual();



        private WriteableBitmap bgImg2 = null;
        private Int32Rect rectimg;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // 初期化処理(Kinectセンサーやバッファ類の初期化)
        private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            kinectChooser.KinectChanged += KinectChanged;
            kinectChooser.Start();
        }

        // 終了処理
        private void WindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            kinectChooser.Stop();
        }

        // Kinectセンサーの挿抜イベントに対し、初期化/終了処理を呼び出す
        private void KinectChanged(object sender, KinectChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.OldSensor != null)
                UninitKinectSensor(args.OldSensor);

            if (args.NewSensor != null)
                InitKinectSensor(args.NewSensor);
        }

        // Kinectセンサーの初期化
        private void InitKinectSensor(KinectSensor kinect)
        {
            // ストリームの有効化
            ColorImageStream clrStream = kinect.ColorStream;
            clrStream.Enable(rgbFormat);

            DepthImageStream depthStream = kinect.DepthStream;
            depthStream.Enable(depthFormat);

            SkeletonStream skelStream = kinect.SkeletonStream;
            kinect.DepthStream.Range = DepthRange.Near;

            skelStream.EnableTrackingInNearRange = true;
            skelStream.TrackingMode = SkeletonTrackingMode.Seated;
            skelStream.Enable();

            // バッファの初期化
            pixelBuffer = new byte[clrStream.FramePixelDataLength];
            depthBuffer = new short[depthStream.FramePixelDataLength];
            skeletonBuffer = new Skeleton[skelStream.FrameSkeletonArrayLength];

            // 画面に表示するビットマップの初期化
            bmpBuffer = new RenderTargetBitmap(clrStream.FrameWidth,clrStream.FrameHeight,96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
            bgImg2 = new WriteableBitmap(clrStream.FrameWidth, clrStream.FrameHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);



            // イベントハンドラの登録
            kinect.AllFramesReady += AllFramesReady;

            faceTracker = new FaceTracker(kinect);

            rectimg = new Int32Rect(0, 0, clrStream.FrameWidth, clrStream.FrameHeight);        
        }

        // Kinectセンサーの終了処理
        private void UninitKinectSensor(KinectSensor kinect)
        {
            if (faceTracker != null)
            {
                faceTracker.Dispose();
                faceTracker = null;
            }
            kinect.AllFramesReady -= AllFramesReady;
        }

        // FrameReady イベントのハンドラ
        // (Kinectセンサーの情報をもとにFaceTrackingを行い、
        //  認識した顔の各点に赤い点を描画)
        private void AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            KinectSensor kinect = sender as KinectSensor;

            using (ColorImageFrame colorImageFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
            using (DepthImageFrame depthImageFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
            using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            {
                if (colorImageFrame == null || depthImageFrame == null || skeletonFrame == null)
                    return;

                // 顔の各点の座標を保持するバッファ
                EnumIndexableCollection<FeaturePoint, Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit.FaceTracking.PointF> facePoints = null;
                EnumIndexableCollection<FeaturePoint, Vector3DF> facePoints3D = null;

                colorImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelBuffer);
                depthImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(depthBuffer);
                skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(skeletonBuffer);


                //描画の準備(左画面)
                var drawContext1 = drawVisual.RenderOpen();
                int frmWidth = colorImageFrame.Width;
                int frmHeight = colorImageFrame.Height;



                rgbImage.Source = bmpBuffer;
                IPLImage.Source = bgImg2;


                // カメラの画像情報から原画像のビットマップを作成し描画(左)
                var bgImg1 = new WriteableBitmap(frmWidth, frmHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
                bgImg1.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, frmWidth, frmHeight), pixelBuffer, frmWidth * 4, 0);

                //右画面の原画像を追加
                bgImg2.WritePixels(rectimg, pixelBuffer, frmWidth * 4, 0);

                var rect1 = new System.Windows.Rect(0, 0, frmWidth, frmHeight);
                drawContext1.DrawImage(bgImg1, rect1);
                //System.Drawing.Pen pen = Pens.White;


                foreach (Skeleton skeleton in skeletonBuffer)
                {
                    // トラックできている骨格だけを対象とする
                    if (skeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked)
                    {  // 今回のフレームにFaceTrackingを適用
                        FaceTrackFrame frame = faceTracker.Track(rgbFormat, pixelBuffer, depthFormat, depthBuffer, skeleton);       
                        //顔情報が認識できなかった場合は0を書き出す
                        //1フレーム毎に顔情報情報を取得する
                        facePoints3D = frame.Get3DShape();
                        facePoints = frame.GetProjected3DShape();

                        var rect2 = new System.Windows.Rect(facePoints[15].X, facePoints[15].Y, 100, 50);
                        if (frame.TrackSuccessful)
                        {
                            //原画像の上から新たに描写
                            drawContext1.DrawRectangle(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red, null, rect2);                    
                            foreach (var facePt in facePoints)
                            {
                                // 取得した顔の各点に赤い点を描画(左)
                                var pt = new System.Windows.Point(facePt.X, facePt.Y);
                                drawContext1.DrawEllipse(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red, null, pt, 1, 1);
                             }
                        }
                    }
                    //if (facePoints != null) { }
                }
                // 画面に表示するビットマップに描画(左)
                drawContext1.Close();
                bmpBuffer.Render(drawVisual);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 質問の前にヘルプ http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask はお読みにになられましたか？どのようにうまくいっていないのか、エラーが出るのか、期待した結果にならないのか、その場合どのような期待をして、実際にはどうなってしまっているのか、などの現象を整理して書かれると回答しやすくなります。また、プログラム全体をただコピーするのではなく、うまくいっていない箇所、メインとなる処理のみを抜粋することで回答者が概要を理解しやすくなりますので、回答がつきやすくなるかと思います。

Comment: [コード例の書き方のヘルプ](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)も参考になると思います。

Comment: すみませんこちらのサイトを使用したのが初めてだったので以後気を付けます。
質問にいたしましては自己解決いたしました。
Cvsharpを使って動画のフレーム毎にtrackingしてきた画像の目元部分を検出→閾値処理→瞳孔の大きさ変化で検出できました

Answer (score 1):

`facePoints`の特徴点はインデックスが決まっていたはずです。[リンク先](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx#ID4EJNAC1)の情報が使用されているバージョンで通用するかはわかりませんが、図の通りなら15以下の点を調べればいいので

```
var minX = facePoints.Take(16).Select(_ => _.X).Min();
var maxX = facePoints.Take(16).Select(_ => _.X).Max();
var minY = facePoints.Take(16).Select(_ => _.Y).Min();
var maxY = facePoints.Take(16).Select(_ => _.Y).Max();
```

という感じで目の領域が分かるかと。